# I've got an error while adding an olcOverlay

Tags: openldap

here is my ldif file :
dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncpro

then I enter ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f overlay.ldif
and here is the error :
value of single-valued naming attribute 'olcOverlay' conflicts with value present in entry.

I even tried to change olc from olcOverlay={0} to olcOverlay={1} but nothing's changed.